# Customizing pin orientation in Altium schematic library

Tags: schematics, altium

In Altium, I want to have the Name of the pin in horizontal orientation while the pin is in vertical orientation like
[image]
But do not get the option in the pin properties dialog box.
[image]

Here, the tutorial shows how to change the orientation. But there is no option for that in my case. Does anyone know how to get that option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what happens when you refer to tutorials for later versions of software than you're running. It's also not present in Altium 9, which is what we're using for boards.

It was [added](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Release+notes+for+Altium+Designer+Version+13.0) in Altium 13.

> Schematic Pin name/designator position, font and color customization.
>
> The pin name and designator position, font and color can now be customized individually.

So to get that option, contact your sales office for an upgrade (or simply install that CD that's sitting on your credenza)

Answer (score 1):

What version of altium are you using? My pin properties dialog has more options. If you look in the red square area in my picture, there are options that allow you to rotate the designator with respect to the pin.

I am using 13.3.4, and I opened it from within the schematic library editor.

[image: edit-pin-dialog]